# Error in the derivative of Poisson Distribution

Tags: error-analysis, statistics

I have a Poisson Distribution $N(x)$ and so I know the error in the $N(x)$. But I want to find the error in $N'(x)$. How to do this?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I remember the Poisson Distribution to be suitable for discrete variables. If this is the case the derivative is not defined.

Comment: see this website: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/416083/error-in-the-derivative-of-poisson-distribution